# Qt Creator debugger doesn't show text contents of char* and wchar_t* variables

Tags: c++, debugging, qt-creator

Qt Creator does not show `char*` or `wchar_t*` variables as strings, while `std::string` and `std::wstring` are shown correctly.

For example for this code:

```
const char *a = "abcd";
const wchar_t *b = L"abcd";
std::string c = "abcd";
std::wstring d = L"abcd";
```

The debuger's Watch Window shows this:

[image]

As you can see, `c` and `d` are shown as text, but `a` and `b` are treated like regular pointers.

Is there a setting that can make it show `char*` and `wchar_t*` the same way it shows `std::string` and `std::wstring`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to keep in mind that a `char*` is a pointer to a `char`. It's not a string by definition; it's just a pointer to a `char`. So the debugger can't really assume that it's a string, unless you explicitly tell it to. To do that, right click on it in the watch window, select "change local display format", and there you can change how the debugger should interpret either just this one variable or all `char*` pointers.

Comment: Unfortunately 'change local display format' doesn't work when you use the CDB debugger on Windows. I'll update this if I find a way to do it.